# Set cron schedule config_path and value for website scope?

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

Saved the cron schedule `config_path` and value with websites scope and scope id but it is not working.

When saved with default scope and scope id 0 in the `core_config_data` table works properly. The group id="default" in crontab.xml.

Any solution to set path and value websites scope for the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command "crontab -l" to check if your cron is already running